# How do I reference the HttpContext.Current.User after the Application_PostAuthenticateRequest in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, httpcontext

So here's a break down of my issue in steps:

1. The user logs in with Google.
2. On the login callback, information about the user is gathered
3. Roles are assigned based on the user
4. A FormsAuthenticationTicket is created which passes the user/roles to the Application_PostAuthenticateRequest in Global.asax
5. In that request a GenericPrinciple is created from the authentication ticket and roles
6. HttpContext.Current.User is set to the above variable

Now my question is, now that I set who the current user is that is using the website, how can I reference them? After the post authenticate complete, I check the current user and it's null. Should I be setting the principle to a different variable other than HttpContext.Current.User?

Callback

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
...
// Get roles for current user
string roles = "bob,adminbob,cthulu";

FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
   1,
   loginInfo.Email,
   DateTime.Now,
   DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // value of time out property
   false,
   roles,
   FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));
Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
...
}
```

Post Authenticate in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

   if (authCookie != null) {
      FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
      string[] userRoles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
      GenericPrincipal userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), userRoles);
      HttpContext.Current.User = userPrincipal; //How do I reference this in the program?
   }
}
```

Comment: If this is the very same request then the cookie is in the Response. It hasn't come back however yet so it is not in the Request, yet you try to read it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I figured out why it was returning blank. When I was calling the method to check the Name, the Identity wasn't authenticated yet. If you try to get the name without it being authenticated, it returns blank.

So I just simply checked with:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```